# null pointer exception in getString servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

I have servlet for web :

```
String value = request.getParameter("valuechannel");
    String type = request.getParameter("type");
    String teller = request.getParameter("teller");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    proses_dbase_user pdb = new proses_dbase_user();
    ArrayList<mo_tell_suc_err> tabtel = new ArrayList<mo_tell_suc_err>();


    try
    {
        tabtel = pdb.disTelSucc(new mo_tell_suc_err(value,type,teller));
        out.print(tabtel);

        JSONObject jso = new JSONObject();

        jso.put("items", tabtel);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(jso);
        out.println(json);
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

for the process database

```
public ArrayList disTelSucc(mo_tell_suc_err mor)throws SQLException
{
    getConnection();
    //pstmt = koneksi.prepareStatement(query); 
    //rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    if(mor.getType().toLowerCase().equals("financial"))
    {
        query = "SELECT trans_code, trans_desc, total_success FROM tb_vw_teller_succ_err_fin WHERE branch=? AND teller=?";

        pstmt.setString(1, mor.getBranch());
        pstmt.setString(2, mor.getTeller());
        pstmt = koneksi.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    }
    else
    {
        query = "SELECT trans_code, trans_desc, total_success FROM tb_vw_teller_succ_err_non_fin WHERE branch=? AND teller==?";

        pstmt.setString(1, mor.getBranch());
        pstmt.setString(2, mor.getTeller());
        pstmt = koneksi.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();  
    }


    while(rs.next())
    {
        mor.setTRX_CODE(rs.getString(1));
        mor.setTRX_DESC(rs.getString(2));
        mor.setTOTAL_SUCCESS(rs.getString(3));

        teller_succ_err.add(mor);
    }
    return teller_succ_err;
}
```

and the model

```
public class mo_tell_suc_err {


private String tempTypeTeller;
private String tempNonFin;
private String tempType;
private String TRX_CODE;
private String TRX_DESC;
private String ERROR_CODE;
private String ERROR_DESC;
private String TOTAL_SUCCESS;
private String TOTAL_ERROR;

public mo_tell_suc_err()
{

}
public mo_tell_suc_err(String tempType,String tempNonFin, String tempTypeTeller)
{
    this.tempType = tempType;
    this.tempNonFin = tempNonFin;
    this.tempTypeTeller = tempTypeTeller;
}
public String getTeller() {
    return tempTypeTeller;
}
public void setTeller(String tempTypeTeller) {
    this.tempTypeTeller = tempTypeTeller;
}
public String getType() {
    return tempNonFin;
}
public void setType(String tempNonFin) {
    this.tempNonFin = tempNonFin;
}
public String getBranch() {
    return tempType;
}
public void setBranch(String tempType) {
    this.tempType = tempType;
}
public String getTRX_CODE() {
    return TRX_CODE;
}
public void setTRX_CODE(String TRX_CODE) {
    this.TRX_CODE = TRX_CODE;
}
public String getTRX_DESC() {
    return TRX_DESC;
}
public void setTRX_DESC(String TRX_DESC) {
    this.TRX_DESC = TRX_DESC;
}
public String getERROR_CODE() {
    return ERROR_CODE;
}
public void setERROR_CODE(String ERROR_CODE) {
    this.ERROR_CODE = ERROR_CODE;
}
public String getERROR_DESC() {
    return ERROR_DESC;
}
public void setERROR_DESC(String ERROR_DESC) {
    this.ERROR_DESC = ERROR_DESC;
}
public String getTOTAL_SUCCESS() {
    return TOTAL_SUCCESS;
}
public void setTOTAL_SUCCESS(String TOTAL_SUCCESS) {
    this.TOTAL_SUCCESS = TOTAL_SUCCESS;
}
public String getTOTAL_ERROR() {
    return TOTAL_ERROR;
}
public void setTOTAL_ERROR(String TOTAL_ERROR) {
    this.TOTAL_ERROR = TOTAL_ERROR;
}
```

}

but I am getting the below exception in my code :

frequent i am getting this error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.bni.dbase.proses_dbase_user.disTelSucc(proses_dbase_user.java:661)
com.bni.user.proses_teller_success.doGet(proses_teller_success.java:51)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

please help me to know where the exception refer to because i've try to change model and process database still nothing happen

thanks be for

Comment: Check the result of `request.getParameter("type");`, validate other parameter values pulled out of `request`. If the expected parameters are not present then report bad request (400).

Comment: And by all that is holy, please read the Java Naming Conventions.

Comment: The stack trace tells you that it's thrown at line 661. Which line is that? What could possibly be null at this line? How about using the debugger, or even log statements, to know?

Comment: pstmt.setString(1, mor.getBranch()); that's the line 661 in my STS the exception in the setString

Comment: Can you share the code for getConnection()? Probably, pstmt is null.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `pstmt.setString(1, mor.getBranch())` before creating `pstmt`. The code should be as follows:

```
pstmt = koneksi.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.setString(1, mor.getBranch());
pstmt.setString(2, mor.getTeller());
```